# Knapsack algorithm, large capacity

Tags: java, algorithm, out-of-memory, knapsack-problem

I'm currently in developing a playlist player and im facing a problem. I have gaps of variable length in my playlist that i want to fill with special audio files. These files also have a variable length, usually shorter then the gap i have in my playlist.

This sounds like a classic knapsack problem, so i tried to implement this algorithm. This works fine for smaller gaps, but whenever i have a gap of 30 minutes the algorithm uses extreme amount of memory. This is expected because im using [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Dynamic_programming) to solve the problem.

The knapsack has a capacity of {gap in milliseconds} and the knapsack items have the weight of the audio files in milliseconds.

This is extremely innefficient. So i was wondering if i could use a different algorithm, or maybe change the weight and capacity into smaller variables. So far i was thinking of dividing everything by an arbitrary number, but il lose precision if i do so.

Anyone has any ideas?

Edit:

I have about 500 fillers to fill the gap. And changing the pitch is not possible. 
The set of fillers should have a perfect solution. 
I really want millisecond precision but I can live with under 100ms off.

Comment: Do you need millisecond accuracy? If so, why? Do you control the length of the gap?

A little context goes a long way.

Comment: Does the gap *have* to be filled optimally? Maybe you should just stop when the new gap is below a certain threshold.

Comment: This sounds very strange.  Where does a gap of 30 Minutes come from?  Why does it have to fit perfectly?  Audio files can easily be stretched by a few percent without any noticeable difference, maybe this helps?

Comment: I've edited the origin question with a little more context

Comment: is precomputation of values possible or is it dynamic ?

Comment: The problem doesnt change during solving, the filler lengths are all known in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said play-list so I'm assuming you have songs, and a typical song is about 3 minutes so your solution will be about 10 songs. Thus you can divide all your times by 50 and then the typical error for a song will be plus or minus 25 milliseconds and so for 10 random songs the error will usually be about (25 milliseconds * sqrt(10)) < 100 milliseconds. If you want better guarantees on the error then you can divide your song times and target time by 20 or 10, but certainly if you divide your times by 10 then you should very, very rarely get an error above 100 milliseconds. And a divide by 10 means you divide memory by 10 for the exact O(WN) dynamic programming solution so it can make the difference between fitting into memory and not if you are on the borderline.

Comment: This is what I went with right now and it seems that I can't further improve the algorithm. I'm gonna try some different numbers and see what works best!

Comment: Where the "25 milliseconds" comes from ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an iterative deepening approximation, where you fill the gap with all the longest fillers that'll fit. Then you remove them (shorter to longer), solving the remaining space with the dynamic algorithm after each one. Since each removal will increase the length of the remaining gap, each problem will be harder. Stop once you run out of time or memory, and use the last generated solution.